# ResourceMoveProviderValidationFailed Error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sql-server, azure-resource-group

while moving VM from one resource group to another this error encountered **while there is no SQL VM associated with VM still getting this error**

```
{
  **"code": "ResourceMoveProviderValidationFailed",**
  "message": "Resource move validation failed. Please see details. Diagnostic information: timestamp '20200908T142742Z', subscription id 'xxx-xxx-xxxx', tracking id 'xxxxxxx-414a-xxxxx-adb4-xxxxxx', request correlation id 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "MissingMoveResources",
      "target": "Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine/SqlVirtualMachines",
      "message": **"Cannot move resource(s) because following resources /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myrgroup/providers/Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine/sqlVirtualMachines/xxxxx0020 need to be included in move request to target resource group as well. Please include these and try again.**"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code **409 MissingMoveResources** is documented in the Azure SQL VM [REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sqlvm/sqlvirtualmachines/update#response) as:

> 409 MissingMoveResources - Cannot move resources(s) because some
> resources are missing in the request.

So, going by the error details posted above, it does mean that the Virtual Machine you're looking at is linked to a SQL Virtual Machine. The easiest way would be to verify it from the Portal itself:

[image: Azure VM blade on Portal]

As seen in the screenshot above:

- Presence of the **SQL Server Configuration** tab under the **Settings** blade, and
- **Publisher** being **MicrosoftSQLServer**

confirm the same.

Therefore, you'd have to know the associated SQL Virtual Machine and include that as well in your request to complete the move operation successfully. You can get to the SQL VM by [accessing the SQL Server configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/manage-sql-vm-portal#access-the-sql-server-configuration-tab) tab.